# Coded UI: Test cases having recording action are failed while executing through custom code

Tags: coded-ui-tests

```
    public void RecordedMethod_Sample(int x)
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        HtmlCell uISALESREVENUECell = this.UIDashboardWindowsInteWindow1.UIDashboardDocument.UITblWrapperOnlineStorTable.UISALESREVENUECell;
        HtmlImage uIImagegifbase64R0lGODImage = this.UIDashboardWindowsInteWindow1.UIDashboardDocument.UIImagegifbase64R0lGODImage;
        HtmlHyperlink uIPostPurchase4Hyperlink = this.UISalesRevenueandGrossWindow.UISalesRevenueandGrossDocument.UIPostPurchase4ReturnsCustom.UIPostPurchase4Hyperlink;
        HtmlDiv uISalesRevenueByDataSoPane = this.UISalesRevenueandGrossWindow.UISalesRevenueandGrossDocument.UISalesRevenueByDataSoPane;
        #endregion

        // Set flag to allow play back to continue if non-essential actions fail. (For example, if a mouse hover action fails.)
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;

        // Mouse hover 'SALES REVENUE' cell at (82, 27)
        Mouse.Hover(uISALESREVENUECell, new Point(82, 27));

        // Reset flag to ensure that play back stops if there is an error.
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;

        // Click 'image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAA...' image
        Mouse.Click(uIImagegifbase64R0lGODImage, new Point(139, 64));

        // Set flag to allow play back to continue if non-essential actions fail. (For example, if a mouse hover action fails.)
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;

        // Mouse hover 'Post Purchase4' link at (144, 19)
        Mouse.Hover(uIPostPurchase4Hyperlink, new Point(144, 19));

        // Reset flag to ensure that play back stops if there is an error.
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;

        // Move 'Sales Revenue By Data Source' pane
        Mouse.StartDragging(uISalesRevenueByDataSoPane, new Point(79, 15));
        Mouse.StopDragging(uISalesRevenueByDataSoPane, 224, -4);
        string title = uISalesRevenueByDataSoPane.InnerText.ToString();
        if (title == "Sales Revenue By Data Source")
        {

        }
```

while Executing Mouse.Hover(uISALESREVENUECell, new Point(82, 27)); it is giving 
following error
Specified method is not supported.
whenever i try to execute it as test case then everything is working as expected
while executing  through custom code it is giving above mentioned error
can anybody please help me out...
thanks in advance for all your inputs

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the `RecordedMethod_Sample`?

Answer (score 0):

What does "custom code" mean? If it means custom controls then the error is likely because the custom control has not been written to support Coded UI. For a custom control to work with Coded UI it must support MSAA or UIA interfaces, or have support from the newer proxy mechanisms.

For more details try web searching for Coded UI, MSAA and UIA. Also have look at this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/05/24/coded-ui-test-new-extensibility-qfe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem.

Your best bet is to use the recorder as much as possible ,and then only move stuff away from UI map when you need dynamic execution and only for those bits.

Let the recorder do all the work for you, and you will get much better reliability during playback.